# catalog price rule apply on sale price

Tags: php, magento, discount

in magento promotions i created a new promotion that gives a discount of 15% on any product
the problem is that the rule calculates the discount on the already discounted special price

There's any way that the promotions will calculate the discount price by using regular price instead of using the special price?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your price rule in the Magento backend, to the tab `Actions` and set `Stop Further Rules Processing` to `Yes`.

Comment: i want the rule to work always but to calculate from the regular price and not on the special price

Answer (score 0):

Go under your promotion rule from admin pannel -> under Action Tab -> Apply -> "MAKE CHANGES REQUIRED FROM DROPDOWN"